# Statements are not allowed in ambient contexts

Tags: typescript

I am using firebase cloud functions and I use Typescript and I made a index.d.ts file in the src directory. I am trying to assign a function to String.prototype. But I get the following error on  `String.prototype`

**Statements are not allowed in ambient contexts.**

and

**An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.**

on `function () {`

```
export {};

declare global {
  interface String {
    capitalize(): string;
  }
}

String.prototype.capitalize = function () {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
};
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: can you share your typescript config or even better setup a reproducable link to [the playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4G4BQaAmwDGAbAQymDgHM8IAjAvRNOOASwDsZgoAzAnEgZRigtSdBgxwEwjGDUYAvYAAoAlAC44AZwFD0DJGj1p+g5qQB0YKBBhWAnmGCnxk6XjkkAvHA4BXZjhiMEMxwyiJwxDDeUMEwABaM6o6xRACCMAoADEqm1gCqYPZQAMIE6opKcADUcHEJpuquPAoAjEroqEA) (you should be able to edit configs until it gives the errors you are getting then save should copy the url to clipboard) because this alone with default configs isn't giving any errors

Comment: [TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=d.ts#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4G4BQaAmwDGAbAQymDgHM8IAjAvRNOOASwDsZgoAzAnEgZRigtSdBgxwEwjGDUYAvYAAoAlAC44AZwFD0DJGj1p+g5qQB0YKBBhWAnmGCnxk6XjkkAvHA4BXZjhiMEMxwyiJwxDDeUMEwABaM6o6xRACCMAoADEqm1gCqYPZQAMIE6opKcADUcHEJpuquPAoAjEroqEA) for folks that want to see the errors in something interactable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two things combined together are the problem:

> I made a index.d.ts file

> I am trying to assign a function to String.prototype.

A `d.ts` file is a [TypeScript declaration file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html). These files only declare types and cannot contain implementation code hence your two errors:

> Statements are not allowed in ambient contexts.

> An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.

Implementation code is code that is not a type annotation or an alternative way of describing this is implementation code is code that is executed during runtime.

You probably aren't intending to write a declaration file – they are often only used to add types to libraries which aren't written in TypeScript. As a result you should rename your file from `index.d.ts` to `index.ts`.

Comment: Renaming the file results in a compiler error: Property 'capitalize' does not exist on type 'StringConstructor'.